# Wordpress - Making a "page" private AND password protected

Tags: wordpress, password-protection

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?  I've found one [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-password/), but it doesn't do the job.  I'm basically using Wordpress as a CMS, and I just want to make one "page" both private and password protected, i.e. you need a password to view the page and it doesn't show up in the menu.

Answer (score 3):

Password protect it in the WP editor and then use [Exclude Pages « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages/) to keep it out of the menu.